# Changing UIView userInteractionEnabled in GestureRecognizer does not work

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to change the UIView during the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` callback. For example:

```
- (void)handleScroll:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.subview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

This never worked in the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` callback, but it did work if I write the code in  the `initWithFrame` method

I also tried using `performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>` in the callback, but neither did it work.

Is there any kind of restriction on what you cannot do in the gesture recognizer callback?

Comment: Check the order of the statement self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: @AshokLondhe So when the recognition begins, I'd like to disable the interactions for all subviews and after it's ended, I'd like them back. The order is what I expected. Do you mean anything specifically?

Comment: if u are using this   if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }   it never works...   instead of NO write YES .

Comment: I've updated question, I AK now changin the subview, but even that didn't work for me.

Comment: what kind of userinteraction func are u using.The above code is working for me.I tried with button

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` in the UIGestureRecognizer. Changing it to YES fixed the problem.